How do I pull all columns from two tables in SqlAlchemy 1.4
I have two ORM models I'm migrating from SqlAlchemy 1.3 and it seems like the relationship is no longer working.
class SomeSpecialType:
    """Stores a SpecialType object as an str"""

    impl = types.String
    python_type = SpecialType

    def process_bind_param(
        self, value: Optional[SpecialType], dialect: Dialect
    ) -> Optional[str]:
        del dialect  # unused
        if value is not None:
            return value.value
        return None

    process_literal_param = process_bind_param

    def process_result_value(
        self, value: Optional[str], dialect: Dialect
    ) -> SpecialType:
        del dialect  # unused
        assert value is not None
        return SpecialType(value)

BaseModel: DefaultMeta = db.Model

class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table_name'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    str_column = Column(String(), nullable=False, index=True)
    special_type = Column(
        SomeSpecialType(),
        nullable=False,
        index=True,
        server_default=SpecialType.SPECIAL.value,
    )

    other_mode = relationship(
        'SomeOtherModel',
        cascade='delete',
        lazy='select',
        uselist=False,
        backref=backref('some_model', lazy='joined'),
    )


class SomeOtherModel(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'some_other_table_name'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    some_model_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey('some_table_name.id'), nullable=False, unique=True
    )
    int_column = Column(Integer, nullable=True)


I'm trying to rewrite my queries into SqlAlchemy 2.0 style to make it future compatible.  My old query is:
created_other_model = SomeOtherModel.query.first()

I've swapped it to
some_other_select = select(SomeOtherModel, SomeModel).join(SomeModel)
self.assertEqual(db.session.scalar(select(func.count(SomeOtherModel.id))), 1)
some_other_instance = db.session.execute(some_other_select).scalar_one()

However, my assert in SomeSpecialType.process_result_value is saying the value is none which leads me to think that the columns from SomeModel are being included like they used to be with 1.3's query
Thoughts on what I'm doing wrong with the query?

Should cluster_config_select be some_other_select in your swapped code?

Your code seems to be using multiple loading mechanisms at once.

lazy="joined" is defined in backref(), which as I understand it uses a LEFT OUTER JOINto loadsome_modelwheneverSomeOtherModel` is requested
.join() is applied during creation of select, which uses an INNER JOIN to connect the two types of models
a 2-tuple of SomeOtherModel and SomeModel is selected instead of just SomeOtherModel's and their properties (including some_model), I'm not exactly just what this does in this situation with the other joins in play.

I think this would more closely reflect the pre-existing code but I would probably avoid using lazy="join" but I'm assuming that is how the existing code is implemented:
class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    # ...

    other_mode = relationship(
        'SomeOtherModel',
        cascade='delete',
        lazy='select',
        uselist=False,
        backref=backref('some_model', lazy='joined'),
    )

# Limit is no longer automatically applied but join should be automatically
# performed based on backref definition.
some_other_select = select(SomeOtherModel).limit(1)
# The object or None, no exception is generated.
some_other_instance = db.session.scalars(some_other_select).first()

I would double check that the backref definition is respected in this case by turning on echo=True on the engine and checking manually in the log output that a LEFT OUTER JOIN is indeed generated automatically.
You can read more about scalars().  Essentially it means get the first item out of whatever tuple you expect from your select(), in this case we just have a 1-tuple so this is just the SomeOtherModel objects themselves.  This at first looks ridiculous but makes it easier and more intuitive to combine core and orm objects in select() statements.  This is explained more in the-select-sql-expression-construct.

Ah, thank you.  I agree that the select I posted wasn't correct, it was the result of flailing to get something to work.  I turned on DB echo and can now see the select statements and they look identical if I use db.session.query(SomeOtherModel).first() which is also failing in the same way.  I don't understand why it's not sending data to SomeSpecialType.process_result_value when SomeModel is a back reference, I see columns from it in the DB query

@simpleCoder I don't have a lot of experience with custom types other than json wrappers.  If you turn off the assert and then inspect the result does it "eventually" come out with a value?

Also I didn't realize you were going from 1.3 to 1.4.  I thought it was 1.4 to 2.0.  I can run the actual example later today and inspect it.

Yeah, I found 1.3 -> 2.0 was too much of a leap so I'm starting with 1.3 -> 1.4

I just tested.  It never gets the value in process_result_value

I'm running this in a test where I add the SomeOtherModel by running sm_model = db.session.query(SomeModel).first() and then smo_model = SomeOtherModel(some_model_id=sm_model.id, int_column=3), db.session.add(smo_model), and then db.session.commit() prior to doing the query.  I know it's added because the count is 1, and I know it can get the SomeModel, because I query that before.  This is why I'm so confused :P

I did some more testing and determined the solution.  I posted it below.  It looks like the problem wasn't the SQL query but the mapping back to the objects via the relationships

After some testing I determined the solution.
In ORM 1.4 the recommended way to do relationships is to swap from backref to back_populates
I swapped my backref's over and added the relationship on the child side and it worked.
Given my example the new code looks like:
...
class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table_name'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    str_column = Column(String(), nullable=False, index=True)
    special_type = Column(
        SomeSpecialType(),
        nullable=False,
        index=True,
        server_default=SpecialType.SPECIAL.value,
    )

    other_model = relationship(
        'SomeOtherModel',
        cascade='delete',
        lazy='select',
        uselist=False,
        back_populates='some_model',
    )


class SomeOtherModel(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'some_other_table_name'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    some_model_id = Column(
        Integer, ForeignKey('some_table_name.id'), nullable=False, unique=True
    )
    some_model = relationship(
        'SomeModel',
        uselist=False,
        back_populates='other_model',
    )
    int_column = Column(Integer, nullable=True)

